# Prepared statements and terrible performances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

There was an application that was changed, so that all queries are performed using prepared statements, rather than regular statements. What happens is that, for every query, the prepared statement is created, used once, dumped.
This is obviously bad for performances, but it is much worse than I could expect.
Please tell me why this query takes 12 seconds **on average** to execute as prepared statement:

```
select top 1 * from Object1 where (Column1 = ?)
```

You can see the plan here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B15cABISr

The table is about one million rows, a few kbytes every row, has a PK and only 4 indexes, including a non-clustered, non-unique index on Column1

What can I do to improve the performances, without returning to regular statements?

Answer (score 2):

**Plan XML**

The query plan XML shows no `<WaitStats>` and the query time stats are `<QueryTimeStats ElapsedTime="0" CpuTime="0" />` & `CompileTime="7" CompileCPU="4"` As far as the query plan is concerned, it should have ran instantly. The query plan shows no issues.

**Build version**

Since your build version is `13.0.4522.0` (`SP1 CU10 + Security Update`)

There is a fix for prepared statements in [SP1 CU13](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4475775/cumulative-update-13-for-sql-server-2016-sp1):

[FIX: "Non-yielding" error occurs when there is a heavy use of prepared statements in SQL Server 2014 and 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4475322/fix-non-yielding-error-occurs-when-there-is-a-heavy-use-of-prepared-st)

You should look into the error log and see if there is any note of such errors.

There is also a different non-yielding scheduler fix in [SP2 CU2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4340355/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2016-sp2).

More examples and information on non-yielding scheduler errors [here](https://blog.pythian.com/sql-server-more-light-shed-on-non-yielding-scheduler-and-indexes-stats/) and [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql-server-timingout-accepts-no-connection-and-needs-reboot-to-recover).

**Fixing the error**

You should patch your instance to at least [SP1 CU13](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4475775/cumulative-update-13-for-sql-server-2016-sp1) or [SP2 CU5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4475776/cumulative-update-5-for-sql-server-2016-sp2), but preferably [SP2 CU8](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4505830/cumulative-update-8-for-sql-server-2016-sp2).